# Add Gmail account to Google Apps account

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-email

I want to send as `user@gmail.com` in my `user@mydomain.com` Google Apps for Business account.

Whenever I try to *Add another email address you own* under accounts in my Google Apps account, I get the following error:

> You must send through gmail.com SMTP servers when you send as user@gmail.com. However, this functionality is not available for your account. Please contact your domain administrator for more information.

I have Super Admin access to the Google Apps (I'm the only user) and I already set *Outgoing SMTP Server* in the Advanced Gmail Settings but it still doesn't work.

Comment: check this article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/132060 which may get  you with some idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the *Allow per-user outbound gateways* option is selected. You can find it in your Google Apps Control Panel (admin.google.com) → *Google Apps* → *Gmail* → *Advanced Settings* → "End User Access" section.

Comment: I had the same problem and I had the checkbox enabled. I fixed it by disabling it. Waiting a few hours and enabling it again. Since then no more problems.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you're on a paid version of Google Apps. A little advertised piece of information is that it’s not available in the legacy free version.

Although the correct answer is to select "Allow per-user outbound gateways" in *Apps* → *Google Apps* → *Settings for Gmail* → *Advanced settings*, this only works in the paid version. To confuse things further, the option is available for legacy unpaid versions (but does not work).

See documentation [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/178333).

> *This feature is not available in the [legacy free edition of Google Apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2855120).*

Hopes this helps.

Comment: You do not have to be on paid version. Legacy free version supports this feature. The linked help article applies only to outbound gateway which is a different feature.